# What's this bug that is pretending to be an ant?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found a bug with a yellow banding in the South of France. At first I thought it was an ant, and then it appeared to be a related to a cricket.

What type of bug is it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the wings, they look partially formed and hard -- this is indicative of this being a [nymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymph_(biology)) of some type of [hemipteran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera). (The developing wings are sometimes called "wing pads").

One group that comes to mind is the family [Miridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miridae) since some species have ant-mimic nymphs.

One possibility (well, one jumping off point) is *Miris striatus* *

[image]

<sup>Credit: Tristan Bantock (2008) ; Source: [BritishBugs](https://www.britishbugs.org.uk/heteroptera/Miridae/miris_striatus.html)</sup>

[GBIF](https://www.gbif.org/species/4487687) confirms this insect is in France.

*I'm not convinced this is your species given the darker limbs and more prominent and abundant yellow in your specimen. Genus seems likely though. [Miridae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miridae) is a very large family of true bugs, so there are *lots* of potential options I'm not even familiar with...

- **Update**: I just returned to this. I'm actually *more certain* this is the OP's species. I think the more prominent abdominal yellow is simply a camera angle causing the two most anterior striations to "blend" to appear as a larger spot. The prominent yellowing in [this image](https://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/aff.-Miris-striatus-img137928.html) [[archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20221108181049/https://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/aff.-Miris-striatus-img137928.html)] appears much more like the OP's specimen.